# Get specific output using php DOMElement and beginning of a value?

Tags: php, html, dom

Here is the HTML code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>value2</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:example@mail.com">mailto:example@mail.com</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And, the php:

```
$html = 'http://www.example.com'; // target path
$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link){

    $linkatt = $link->getAttribute('href');
    $linkval = substr($linkatt, 0, 5 );

    if($linkval == "mailto"){
        echo $link->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Tried to export all child `a` elements with `href` attribute by looking for the starting "mailto" value and got no results so, not sure what is wrong with my code...

How can I get it done, exporting all the values of `href` attribute starting with `mailto`... ?

Comment: `tr` has __no__ `href` attribute. `a` which is in `td` __has__.

Comment: `$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');` That already sounds wrong. `td`s are not links. Try `$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');`

Comment: thanks @u_mulder, question edited.

Comment: Now: `td` has __no__ `href` attribute. `a` which is in `td` __has__.

Comment: Got it, thanks guys you are great!

Comment: `substr($linkatt, 0, 5)` will take __5__ symbols. `mailto` has __6__.

Comment: You keep changing the example code in your question. Please don't do that if it doesn't reflect the original problem anymore.

Comment: Excuse me @DecentDabbler, wasn't sure how to ask both questions together clearly, I will consider removing it if it's not useful... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load HTML from a filename/URL, you need to use `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`, not `DOMDOcument::loadHTML()`. The latter expects a string of HTML, not a filename or URL.